# How come printing a string(an Object) in java prints it?

Tags: java, string, object

When we do:

```
String string = new String("Ralph");
//This creates a reference called string that points to a sequence of 
//characters in memory
```

This is the same as:

```
String string = "Ralph";
```

When we print both, we get the actual value of the string.
If we print any other object in Java, we get an address for that object.
My question is, is there any dereferencing that is taking place behind the scenes?

Comment: What you get for any other object is its `toString()` method, not an "address". The `toString()` of `Object` prints its class name and hash code.

Comment: String overrides the Object.toString() method. All other classes can also do it. If they do, the returned String will be printed when printing the object.

Comment: From docs (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toString%28%29) - "This object (which is already a string!) is itself returned."

Answer (score 3):

When you pass an object reference to the `System.out.println()` method, for
example, the object's `toString()` method is called, and the returned value of `toString()` is shown in the following example:

```
public class HardToRead {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        HardToRead h = new HardToRead();
        System.out.println(h);
    }
}
```

Running the HardToRead class gives us the lovely and meaningful,

```
% java HardToRead
HardToRead@a47e0
```

Now,
Trying to read this output might motivate you to override the `toString()`
method in your classes, for example,

```
public class BobTest {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Bob f = new Bob("GoBobGo", 19);
        System.out.println(f);
    }
}

class Bob {
    int shoeSize;
    String nickName;
    Bob(String nickName, int shoeSize) {
        this.shoeSize = shoeSize;
        this.nickName = nickName;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return ("I am a Bob, but you can call me " + nickName +". My shoe size is " + shoeSize);
    }
}
```

This ought to be a bit more readable:

```
% java BobTest
I am a Bob, but you can call me GoBobGo. My shoe size is 19
```

Answer (score 1):

The class `String` is a special class in Java.
But it gets out printed the same way every other class does.
If we call `System.out.println("Ralph")` the function `println` takes that String and then displays it.

The class `Object`s `toString()` method is implemented, so it displays the hash code of the Object, by calling the `hashCode()` function. If you overwrite the `toString()` method, it will display something else.

If you take any object other than a `String` and give it to a method that takes a `String` (or in fact cast it to a `String`) java will call the `toString()`method of that Object, to convert it to a `String`.

So 'printing' always does the same thing, it's just implemented in different ways, using the  `toString()` method.

Comment: Again, not the memory address. Certainly not in 64 bit systems where int is 32 bit. It's the hash code of the object.

Answer (score 0):

`new String("Ralph")` copies the character data array of the literal string and stores it in the new String instance.

However, you only get the address of an object when you print it because printing uses the `toString()` method of that object. If that method is not implemented, the default implementation defined in `Object` is used, which returns the class name plus the hash code (that seems like an address if `hashCode()` is not implemented).

Comment: Not reference. Hash code, from the `hashCode()` method. In hexadecimal.

Comment: I know, but it is the reference ID in case `hashCode()` is not implemented.

Comment: Define "reference ID", then. It may be based on the memory address of the object, but that is not a requirement of the language, and certainly requires some manipulation in 64 bit systems.

Comment: I don't think this is relevant for the question, I was only pointing it out to him. But by reference ID, I meant the identity hash code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the primary types are printed with auto dereferencing`String, int, float, etc.`, while the objects other than primary types, only with de-referencing function `object.toString()` that are implemented on the object level.